# Can't install some dependencies into projects (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I was struggling with this for the last 2 days
I can't install the project dependencies inside the project folder
I don't know if it's a problem with the project
That's the Project repo on github in case that would help
https://github.com/DeanShooster/NodeJS-BookStore

```
$ npm install
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\FPCC\Desktop\Web Development\NodeJS-BookStore\node_modules\bcrypt
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\FPCC\Desktop\Web Development\NodeJS-BookStore\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\FPCC\Desktop\Web Development\NodeJS-BookStore\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi 
--napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.8
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@19.0.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\FPCC\Desktop\Web Development\NodeJS-BookStore\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install request to https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/611333/2dce3380-7741-11eb-8e53-10fe9e70e497?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20221115%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20221115T114040Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=cea9b3203437b7c07a048b48de00309b6a19c51b47db7310c5c957805d904f1d&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=611333&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dbcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 185.199.110.133:443
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@5.0.1 and node@19.0.1 (node-v111 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error request to https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/611333/2dce3380-7741-11eb-8e53-10fe9e70e497?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20221115%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20221115T114040Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=cea9b3203437b7c07a048b48de00309b6a19c51b47db7310c5c957805d904f1d&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=611333&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dbcrypt_lib-v5.0.1-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 185.199.110.133:443
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@19.0.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@19.0.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.0 found at "C:\Users\FPCC\python3.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)   
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:364:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:385:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:420:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\FPCC\\Desktop\\Web Development\\NodeJS-BookStore\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\napi-v3\\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\FPCC\\Desktop\\Web Development\\NodeJS-BookStore\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\napi-v3" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\FPCC\Desktop\Web Development\NodeJS-BookStore\node_modules\bcrypt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v19.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\FPCC\Desktop\Web Development\NodeJS-BookStore\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\FPCC\Desktop\Web Development\NodeJS-BookStore\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\FPCC\Desktop\Web Development\NodeJS-BookStore\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\FPCC\\Desktop\\Web Development\\NodeJS-BookStore\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\FPCC\Desktop\Web Development\NodeJS-BookStore\node_modules\bcrypt
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v19.0.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.8
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\FPCC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-15T11_40_05_764Z-debug-0.log

---
```

I tried all solutions I found on Google but nothing worked for me

Comment: We don’t know what you’ve tried. Did you read the suggested link https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows?

Comment: May be try deleting the old package-lock.json file and then run npm install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `npm install -g windows-build-tools`.

It will take a long time, but it should generally resolve your issues.
There are often many problems withs windows and `node-gyp`.